# Need Help about inspect iOS logs

Tags: ios, firebase, crash-log

[image]App is randomly crash, I need help how can I fix this issue.

```
Incident Identifier: 04F85797-68FE-4212-A6BB-76B34CD76168
CrashReporter Key:   3e386d5d388ab1e0948622c634100f2ed031247b
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             dtac [1085]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/dtac
Identifier:          th.co.crie.dtacservices
Version:             96 (6.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2017-03-09 18:20:14.14 +0700
Launch Time:         2017-03-09 18:20:06.06 +0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  4

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
2.504798     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181ce98e0 TCP Conn 0x137939250 SSL Handshake DONE
2.611388     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181ce97f0 TCP Conn 0x137939250 starting SSL negotiation
2.612172     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181d8be7c TCP Conn 0x137939250 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
2.613957     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181d8d3a8 TCP Conn 0x137939250 event 1. err: 0
2.664198     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181d8d480 TCP Conn 0x137939250 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816bcc60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ba964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815e4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182ecc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
6   UIKit                           0x00000001868d2088 UIApplicationMain + 204
7   dtac                            0x00000001000475bc main (main.m:16)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001811828b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a14d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001811647d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181153648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: FIRAMonitorQueue
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816cfb48 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 5804
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816cf3f0 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 3924
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ce464 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
3   Foundation                      0x0000000181fea320 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 168
4   dtac                            0x00000001008d8298 FIRLogBasic + 212
5   dtac                            0x00000001008af378 -[FIRAASLLogger logMessage:messageCode:withLogLevel:] + 180
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001811514bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115147c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115d4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181154f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.fira.worker
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181285014 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018136297c _os_semaphore_wait + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115c378 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 560
3   dtac                            0x000000010089f408 -[FIRAMonitor monitoringDataForDispatchWithSamplePeriod:lastSampledTimestamp:] + 168
4   dtac                            0x000000010089ac60 __34-[FIRAMeasurement bundleRawEvents]_block_invoke + 6108
5   dtac                            0x0000000100877a08 -[FIRASqliteStore performTransaction:] + 92
6   dtac                            0x0000000100899420 -[FIRAMeasurement bundleRawEvents] + 172
7   dtac                            0x0000000100893800 -[FIRAMeasurement uploadData] + 296
8   dtac                            0x000000010089df44 __50-[FIRAMeasurement handleAppWillResignActiveEvent:]_block_invoke_2 + 36
9   dtac                            0x00000001008a51cc __52-[FIRAScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 44
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001811514bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115147c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115d4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181154f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816bcc60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ba964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815e4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181d65bcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820dbe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136bb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136ba8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369028 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  GAIThread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816bcc60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ba964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815e4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181ff4cfc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Foundation                      0x000000018204a030 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   dtac                            0x0000000100440e0c +[GAI threadMain:] + 64
8   Foundation                      0x00000001820dbe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136bb28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136ba8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369028 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0344 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816c31c8 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136bb28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136ba8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369028 thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284e54 mach_msg + 72
2   dtac                            0x0000000100826944 CLSMachExceptionServer + 232
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136bb28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136ba8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369028 thread_start + 4

Thread 15 name:  Dispatch queue: io.answers.EventQueue :: NSOperation 0x137b4f900 (QOS: BACKGROUND)
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001811c920c __fts_open + 368
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001811c919c __fts_open + 256
2   libremovefile.dylib             0x000000018119164c __removefile_tree_walker + 72
3   libremovefile.dylib             0x0000000181191ac8 removefile + 144
4   Foundation                      0x00000001820338c0 -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] + 172
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182002e48 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182033368 -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 84
7   dtac                            0x00000001008521ac -[ANSAnswersController uploader:didFinishUploadWithUniqueName:error:] + 340
8   dtac                            0x000000010084cb7c -[ANSUploader handleTaskDescription:completedWithError:] + 104
9   dtac                            0x000000010084caf4 -[ANSUploader handleTask:completedWithError:] + 124
10  dtac                            0x00000001008524c4 __98-[ANSAnswersController uploader:completedRequest:withResponse:uniqueName:error:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 208
11  dtac                            0x00000001008495c4 __111-[ANSNetworkRetryHandler handleCompletedRequest:withResponse:forIdentifier:maxRetries:error:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 236
12  dtac                            0x000000010085c314 __84+[FABNetworkResponseHandler handleCompletedResponse:forOriginalRequest:error:block:]_block_invoke + 256
13  dtac                            0x000000010085c034 +[FABNetworkResponseHandler clientResponseType:handler:] + 272
14  dtac                            0x000000010085c1a0 +[FABNetworkResponseHandler handleCompletedResponse:forOriginalRequest:error:block:] + 304
15  dtac                            0x000000010084946c -[ANSNetworkRetryHandler handleCompletedRequest:withResponse:forIdentifier:maxRetries:error:completionHandler:] + 260
16  dtac                            0x0000000100849338 -[ANSNetworkRetryHandler handleCompletedRequest:withResponse:forIdentifier:error:completionHandler:] + 128
17  dtac                            0x0000000100852390 -[ANSAnswersController uploader:completedRequest:withResponse:uniqueName:error:completionHandler:] + 264
18  dtac                            0x000000010084ce64 -[ANSUploader URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] + 288
19  CFNetwork                       0x0000000181e14930 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke170 + 72
20  Foundation                      0x00000001820c0540 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
21  Foundation                      0x0000000182012870 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
22  Foundation                      0x0000000182002e48 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604
23  Foundation                      0x00000001820c2934 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115147c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115d4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181154f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018115f0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812a0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17 name:  com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181284e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816bcc60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ba964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815e4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181ff4cfc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   dtac                            0x000000010094b65c -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] (FSRWebSocket.m:1840)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001820dbe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136bb28 _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018136ba8c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181369028 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000016e1b9c78   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0xffffffffffffffe8   x3: 0x000000016e1b9ca8
    x4: 0x000000016e1b9cc0   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x00000001816d1974   x7: 0x000000016e1ba0b0
    x8: 0x0000000000000007   x9: 0x00000001816d1c4c  x10: 0x000000016e1b99e0  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x000000016e1b9c78  x13: 0x00000001816d1c74  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000008
   x16: 0x0000000000000004  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016e1b97e0
   x20: 0x000000016e1ba048  x21: 0x0000000137a94c51  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000007
   x24: 0x000000016e1ba0a2  x25: 0x000000016e1ba0a8  x26: 0x000000016e1b9c78  x27: 0x000000019f7ec150
   x28: 0x000000016e1ba0a1  fp: 0x000000016e1bab80   lr: 0x00000001816cf3f0
    sp: 0x000000016e1b97e0   pc: 0x00000001816cfb48 cpsr: 0xa0000000

Binary Images:
0x100030000 - 0x100ca3fff dtac arm64  <de5710e543a13793a096b4829c159ec4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/dtac
0x10189c000 - 0x1018dbfff OmiseSDK arm64  <5ea636fab40c35d1929f5965810b354b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/OmiseSDK.framework/OmiseSDK
0x101a88000 - 0x101cabfff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <26f02eda79fe32b9bd99bd076b4736dd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x101f54000 - 0x101f63fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <76ef8da9d2ae340c855718d201c56fc0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x101f98000 - 0x101f9ffff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <4f5c1d312b0b3d458307ff3b01d6678f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x101fc0000 - 0x101fc7fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <7613bac0954c3275bbd6a8f94ca88169> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x101fdc000 - 0x101ff7fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <ac9c450ccc64357d8f60f072ae05fa66> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x102050000 - 0x102113fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <9db043c49ae43c6d9c0b3f4122ccb651> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x102228000 - 0x10222ffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <1bffd5d6067733b3baec046295dea090> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x10224c000 - 0x102253fff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib arm64  <6f1e015a1ea339718a6f88759034b452> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
0x102270000 - 0x10229bfff libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib arm64  <cf91f0ed0bb83262b8ad5f62f496dd99> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
0x102368000 - 0x102373fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <7c39c85d94f234d8bad49faa7fba7a8a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3997CEBD-4F74-4C98-97D9-DD7EC71831B1/dtac.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x1200a8000 - 0x1200d7fff dyld arm64  <a1862e29910f3f069a363730df77dad7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x180cec000 - 0x180cedfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <5bb501a091dc3a22a5544d34a4312de1> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x180cf0000 - 0x180d42fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <9ec0d9dcf728349582c26a7da72f0364> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x180d44000 - 0x180d63fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <aaa40b7f52513cf79c6f814b133556a7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x180d64000 - 0x1810d0fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <939f392022903f2da2858e676e4191ef> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1810d4000 - 0x1810d8fff libcache.dylib arm64  <43424f4c7252330ca92c1a865da896e1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1810dc000 - 0x1810e7fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e47d758d207e32c8ab546b59785d2ab8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1810e8000 - 0x1810ebfff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <b77c451c7ffb356fb3c8368cac95d8f3> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1810ec000 - 0x1810f3fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <1c1678aa36073b42b4406c6dbb06e9f0> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1810f4000 - 0x18114ffff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <b42ff635d1303d45bafe057e5a1e6243> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x181150000 - 0x18117efff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <65568801b7463adeb6e20dc25d14d801> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x181180000 - 0x181182fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <89518667b02d3d1680929e246eb35939> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x181184000 - 0x181184fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <fbb5f1442c3039188da689963efde4d8> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x181188000 - 0x18118cfff libmacho.dylib arm64  <1f37b179ad26307192b3b763ba5f816a> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x181190000 - 0x181191fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <267c6cbaf2193309bd8a191fad38cc79> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x181194000 - 0x1811aafff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <fffe50d37b1c3f92af6f4a68a6d60068> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1811ac000 - 0x1811adfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8bbf799e57f93ed1be24cf2ce6c221a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1811b0000 - 0x18122ffff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <c3408ef0608b3d68acc24d59d6af9528> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x181230000 - 0x181233fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <c5ce1ced5659354ab63871b42d04a7cd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x181234000 - 0x181237fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <504648cfa43d3668b9678b74e33697f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x181238000 - 0x181239fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <8f94549c633036aa99efb0f067031a05> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18123c000 - 0x181252fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <498e424eb31f3d5cb49523cec07f339d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x181254000 - 0x18125cfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <573c3639fde83e87885bfe02c057538d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x181260000 - 0x181282fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <932df5ba705a3b6d948c5dcff196ea6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x181284000 - 0x1812a5fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <fd5f89b7e48c3bc3b3464805d726450d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1812a8000 - 0x1812c4fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a97bf91d4a233dbc94bef06734a2eac0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1812c8000 - 0x1812e1fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <a8af95191b283ca9aa7f9cf80c459bf5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1812e4000 - 0x181347fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a8e4200aecc73e56a8458a0e9cb4a6f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x181348000 - 0x181351fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <d1a7579c71943631845c2908d69bfbc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x181354000 - 0x18135efff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <da8d7d155da230d287a67c46e9b3ccbc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x181360000 - 0x181365fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <4386956061113d7a9e415e543b1243bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x181368000 - 0x181370fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <8e409f0b333f3749b544b337154247b2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x181374000 - 0x181376fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <b673378c7a6236c69b3b35f3b6520807> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x181378000 - 0x181388fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <7de1ebaaeb5f3a5893337941c4c25d8f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x18138c000 - 0x181391fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b0067e5ea3ca3b28abc5cb7d50390363> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x181394000 - 0x181394fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <630bf4c89edf3935b7afe56abdb5caad> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x181398000 - 0x1813bdfff libxpc.dylib arm64  <fc63a0a505523f7fac2c4ea9d9662ba1> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1813c0000 - 0x1815c5fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <d1856fdadee0393ebd636fa4020a454b> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1815c8000 - 0x1815d9fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <8fcb56adfdc13e9593582266b1e4ac18> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1815dc000 - 0x18195cfff CoreFoundation arm64  <182fd72b7fdf330b8dbf70db93af6b63> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x181960000 - 0x181970fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <d045301bcacc37d785d754d5c978d979> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x181974000 - 0x181974fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <c4ee08bffdfc3ce0990c1fbeb858f9dc> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x181978000 - 0x1819e9fff IOKit arm64  <81620a37c2073ceeb9f474604f2c828b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1819ec000 - 0x181a0cfff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <9cc485a12c323768a6b6e88d973bd44e> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x181a10000 - 0x181afafff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <d6c7d4fa4ab033ea94a89058ae09b14b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x181afc000 - 0x181b6efff Security arm64  <4c7468d385513e4db673ec80c318ee20> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x181b70000 - 0x181bc9fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <92717250c7393c44878d137773604d46> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x181bcc000 - 0x181cb4fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <c703a175f1c43ed28d81b839ba961183> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x181cb8000 - 0x181f4cfff CFNetwork arm64  <e65cd15333e435b5975900dc9111f58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x181f50000 - 0x181f5dfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <8ebfd413e3fd3889b546857fcf554b6f> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x181f60000 - 0x181f79fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <68bb861dc8bd3547b5ace073ed504b14> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x181f7c000 - 0x181f96fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <1a2c1f709f213faf81fd2223b719c899> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x181f98000 - 0x181fc2fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <bf6ae1a9c965363ba9f10ff0ca32ee7c> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x181fc4000 - 0x181fe2fff libextension.dylib arm64  <8a88fb35fee03a36ae138e676b9a0e9f> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x181fe4000 - 0x181fe5fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <cdb184e30c3c303694a96b3150520673> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x181fe8000 - 0x182256fff Foundation arm64  <7cf4edf781cb30438b812ded8716cd95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x182258000 - 0x182303fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <097b7e769a3439ad8fdb3abb0edc9daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x182304000 - 0x182669fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <566419f65c9338599694a04da8e20fbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x18266c000 - 0x1828d1fff vImage arm64  <789df1b35e183397803583a25feff3c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1828d4000 - 0x1828f6fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3c655ae6f62035bbba069387c490efbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1828f8000 - 0x18290bfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <94d099e954d638e39ef1773639ef61af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x18290c000 - 0x18291bfff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <80ca4fb770613c76b2449daf05c6dc25> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x18291c000 - 0x182988fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f4e8d68f55af3511a28a616737dcc354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18298c000 - 0x18298cfff vecLib arm64  <546ad53c3a4a36709fdf6e50b76b2ec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x182990000 - 0x182990fff Accelerate arm64  <a1953e95570a3de6a923a812ffbd90ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x182994000 - 0x182ebffff CoreGraphics arm64  <f58e942f6bd039dc8de98619e53500bf>
```

Comment: the application fails from the thread 4 on a so called FIRAMonitorQueue, and appears to be in the logMessage function

Comment: This should be tagged [firebase] and reported to Firebase as well. Seeing the same crashes in the latest version of their SDK.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this. I am facing the same issue